# Opencart, ignore default footer and header files

Tags: javascript, php, html, opencart

I wrote a custom HTML e-mail with a specific header and footer but it adds the default one too from header.tpl and footer.tpl files which are located at

```
catalog/view/theme/default/template/mail
```

Is there a way to make it ignore them for this one specific (newsletter.tpl) file? Because I need the default ones for others at the moment.

It currently looks something like this:

```
+------------------+
|   default-LOGO   |   <- I need to ignore this
+------------------+
+------------------+
|    new-LOGO      |
+------------------+
|                  |
|    CONTENT       |
|                  |
|                  |
+------------------+
|   new-FOOTER     |
+------------------+
+------------------+
| default-FOOTER   |   <- and this
+------------------+
```

Comment: I don't see e-mail header / footer templates being used in OpenCart's mail functionality.  What version are you using?

Comment: @SamotnyPocitac Where can I unset it?

Comment: unset it in the controller you have created with the file for the view.

Comment: There are no files you are mentioning in default installation. Are these files the result of Your work or are they coming with some extension You have installed? Probably You have something like `<?php echo $header; ?>` and `<?php echo $footer; ?>` in this template, but I cannot be sure as there no such files in default OC.